# membership provider in asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

has it changed at all since the previous version? Is there a better / lean alternative? (Open source)

Comment: the membership provider that comes with asp.net. is it different in the new 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not many significant differences, while some improvements are made. You can virtually port your previous projects without any hassle to .NET 4 membership.

Comment: where can i see a list of changes?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this website that discusses breaking changes with asp.net v4. With reference to Membership, some of the basic classes (e.g., MembershipUser, RoleProvider, etc) have been moved to another assembly: System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll.

[ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770156)